# Can I use SelectComponents with measurements that take into account the value of underlying pixels?

Tags: image-processing

Normally, we can ask for the mean, median, etc. underlying pixel values for morphological components with the command:

```
ComponentMeasurements[{MorphologicalComponents[img], img}, "MeanIntensity"]
```

I'm looking to use SelectComponents to select components based on their mean or median underlying pixel values.  However, commands like the following:

```
SelectComponents[{MorphologicalComponents[img], img}, "MeanIntensity", # < 0.4 &];
```

Seem to simply fail.  Is there a way to proceed?

Clarification - Actually, let me be a bit more specific about my question.  I mean to first select MorphologicalComponents of a modified version of the image, specifically after running a filter on it.  I then want to prune morphological components based on pixel values in the original unfiltered image.  So I'd like to do something like this:

```
SelectComponents[{MorphologicalComponents[LaplacianFilter[img,3]], img}, "MeanIntensity", # < 0.4 &];
```

Comment: So maybe you want to work on `MeanFilter[img, r]` instead of `img`?

Comment: @Kuba Hmm, that doesn't quite do what I'd like.  I need to use this as a filter for MorphologicalComponents selected by some metric, and MeanFilter also smears out the image a bit.

Comment: "to select components based on their mean or median underlying pixel values" - I understand this as using `ComponentMeasurements` on `MeanFilter[img, r]`, later you can reffer those positions to postions in orginal image. But maybe I have misunderstood your question, if so, I'm sorry :)

Comment: You can just supply the image to `SelectComponents` and it will compute the `MorphologicalComponents` automatically: `SelectComponents[img, "MeanIntensity", # < 0.4 &];`

Comment: @SimonWoods Huh... never thought to try that.

Comment: @SimonWoods I've clarified my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ComponentMeasurements` and explicitly remove those components which don't satisfy the requirement:

```
m = MorphologicalComponents[LaplacianFilter[img, 3]];
test = # < 0.4 &;

m /. Cases[ComponentMeasurements[{m, img}, "MeanIntensity"], 
    HoldPattern[i_ -> v_] /; ! test[v] :> (i -> 0)]
```

Alternatively, it looks like the internal implementation of `SelectComponents` takes separate arguments for an image and a component matrix:

```
Image`MorphologicalOperationsDump`oSelectComponents[img, m, "MeanIntensity", test, Null]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it's very good.